# How to get confirmation of transaction using Bitcoin j implementaion

Tags: bitcoinj

I am using BitcoinJ lib for creating wallet and transaction.But now I want to know the confirmation count.So, is there any method which can give confirmation count

Answer (score 1):

Use `Wallet.getTransactions(boolean)`. This returns a `Set<Transaction>`:

```
boolean includeDeadTransactions = true;
Set<Transaction> transactions = wallet.getTransactions(includeDeadTransactions);

for (Transaction t : transactions) {
    //Do something
}
```

You will get all transactions you can looping over so you get each transaction details.